# Vue 3 Vite production build redirects to nginx 404 or root page

Tags: docker, vue.js, nginx, vuejs3, vite

I'm deploying my vue3 SPA using docker, While deploying I find that while refreshing the page it redirects to nginx 404 page. On further research I've updated the docker file to change the nginx config file. Now when I refresh the page it redirects to the first page. I cant got to any other url by typing it on the browser

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM node:alpine AS build
WORKDIR /client
COPY package*.json .
RUN npm ci
COPY . .
ARG VITE_BASE_URL
ENV VITE_BASE_URL $VITE_BASE_URL
RUN ["npm", "run", "build"]

FROM nginx:alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=build /client/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

This is the nginx.conf file

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name  localhost;

  root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index  index.html index.htm;

  location /{
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}
```

I've also found the same issue in React app too, it was also vite build.